# How long do objects created by Dagger 2 remain in Android / how does Dagger 2 play with the Android Activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Let's say we have a `@Singleton` application module that creates and returns a `Hashmap` for storing configuration data. If the configuration data is modified in the hashmap and the android application goes into the background and let's say onPause() and onStop() are called.

- Will the hashmap that was created by dagger be destroyed?
- If the app comes back into the foreground will the existing configuration data that was added to the hashmap still exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does Dagger 2 play with the Android Activity lifecycle?

It won't. But you can.

Dagger ceates nothing but Pojos. Pojos that know about dependencies and give them to you when you require them. Nothing less and nothing more.

How you use those objects (components) is entirely up to you.

As most examples show it, there is an `AppComponent` in general, kept in the `Application`, and some sort of `ActivtiyComponent` for each `Activity`.

The `AppComponent` is kept in the application, to share its lifecycle—if the application gets killed or recreated, so does the component, so do your objects.

The `ActivityComponent` is created and kept within the activtiy. Once again, if the activity gets recreated, so does the component. It is nothing but an object assigned to a field inside your activity.

### So why is there a difference between the app and the activity component?

The application component will only reference the application context, and provide classes that can be provided without further information.

The activity component will also have information about the activity. It can access views, fragment handlers, and so on: Activity stuff! You create a new component for every activity because if you don't use dagger you'd also use the current activity and not reference (and leak!) the same one everywhere.

### To answer your question

If it is not clear by now, if you create your `HashMap` within the `AppComponent` (and `@Scope` it!), it will be the same `HashMap` in your entire application, if you properly use your `AppComponent`. It will be destroyed once the app gets terminated along with your `Application` instance.

If you create it within your `ActivityComponent` it will have the same lifecycle as the activity object. You would possibly have to reinitialize things in `onCreate` if `savedInstanceState` contains your data.

---

All this said, don't use static variables. If you assign your components to static variables they will destroy the setup and lead to memory leaks.

If you create your component in `onCreate` you will be fine without any other setup. Just don't use a static variable to hold the component, but make sure it lies within your activity or application respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details explanation. Do you know when the application component will be cleaned up? Is the Application instance cleaned up when the main activity has onStop() called and it goes into the background / task list. Or does it still persist?

Comment: @dazza5000 you the application component would be cleaned up along with the application in this example. the application is long lasting, it will be destroyed when the user kills your app or removes all activities from the recents view (and there are no services runnning, or somthing similar). But in general you need not to worry about your application, it will be the first object there and the last one gone